# React-Hook-Form vs the AntD Form buit in?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd, formik, react-hook-form

we can see the comparison between Formik vs React-Hook-Form somewhere, I have a question about using or comparing the built-in Form Ant Design / MaterialUI vs Reat-hook-form. Why we need the third party despite of using the built-in - pros / cons ? I'm trying to search / research but it seems to hard to understand with my current level.

Comment: I used to use `AntD` in my last job and while I really like the `react-hook-form` API, I had to stick with `AntD` form API because it has better integration with AntD stack for obvious reason. For other UI frameworks that don't have a form API like Material-UI, I use `react-hook-form` which is a superior choice nowadays.

Comment: I think RHF is better than AntD Forms, AntD uses rc-form behind the scenes which isn't up to par with what RHF offers.